# resources in surjunctive groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory

Are there any free available resources on surjunctive groups which are available to say: a graduate level student?

A textbook would be fine also.

Regards.

Comment: Did you look at the references at the Wikipedia entry? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjunctive_group There's a reference to a chapter of a Springer book. Also, note that Gromov showed that sofic groups are surjunctive. However, there are no known non-sofic groups. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sofic_group

Comment: yes, I did, thank you, do you know of any resources which are freely available, thanks in advance.

Comment: @St Georg, the community at mathoverflow does not seem to mind greetings very much, and occasionally appreciates them. Also, removing greetings is a really minor edit.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8592391/bok%253A978-3-642-14034-1.pdf

Comment: @St Georg: Regarding my previous comment, please read http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/410/removing-greetings-and-taglines/

Comment: @IanAgol could you post your comment as an answer please? So it doesn't look like an unanswered question? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a book "[Cellular automata and groups](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8592391/bok%253A978-3-642-14034-1.pdf)" through the [Wikipedia page on surjunctive groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjunctive_group).